# JavaScript of toggle not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript

JavaScript of toogle is properly working in Mozilla but not in Google Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleMe(id) {
    var image = document.getElementById(id);
    if (id.style.display == "block") {
     id.style.display = "none";
    } else {
     id.style.display = "block";
    }
  }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing from your code that you are passing an `id` as string (that what `getElementById` would expect). But then you access properties on the same string. I think you probably wanted to access the style property on the `image` object instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(id) {
    var image = document.getElementById(id);
    if(image.style.display == "block") {
        image.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        image.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes i'm passing id by auto increment i.e in while loop...in mozila showing properly but in chrom it is not working...

Comment: after passind image as a string...toggle not working in mozila also

Comment: calling function onmouseover and mouseout

Answer (score 0):

You're using id instead of image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleMe(id) {
     var image = document.getElementById(id);
     if(image.style.display == "block") {
        image.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        image.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here's the correct code.
:)

Comment: why is else not closed.??